# When to answer a question with 沒有?

Tags: yes-no-questions

I've just started learning Mandarin and I was curious as to when it is appropriate to answer a yes/no question negatively with 沒有.  Obviously, if the question involves 有 then it makes sense.  However, I understand that

你在做飯嗎？

could also be answered that way as well.

I also understand that questions about being, such as

你是老師嗎？

should be answered instead with 不是。

Is this a general rule?  That is, unless the question is about being or state, is it safe to assume that I can respond with 沒有?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to 你在做飯嗎？is still 是 or 不是 . To answer 有 or 沒有, the question should be 你有做飯嗎？

Example:

- You see your friend washing vegetable, and ask 你在做飯嗎？ (are you cooking dinner?) and his answer could be 是 (yes) or 不是 (no)
- A wife came home and saw her husband eating pizza, so she asked 你有做飯嗎？(have you cooked dinner?) the answer could be 有 (I have) or 沒有 (I have not)

> If the question is 你做飯嗎? (are you cooking (now)?/do you cook (regularly)? ) then you can answer according to the context.
>
> If you mean 'I am not cooking now' then you would say '不是' (no)
>
> If you mean 'I don't cook = 'I haven't been cooking regularly' then you can answer '沒有' (I have not)

Comment: So, in order to answer with 有 or 沒有, the question should involve 有?

Comment: yes, stated clearly or implied clearly

Comment: For example, you see your co-worker eating store bought sandwich for lunch everyday, and ask '你做飯嗎?' (do you cook?) He can answer '我不做飯' (I don't cook) or 我沒有做飯 (I did not cook/ I have not been cooking)